# Graphql useSubscription not giving response everytime

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using Graphql useSubscription hook to hit a websocket api but there seems to be an issue. I am only receiving data when i enter the component for the first time or when i go back to some other component and come back again, when trying to refresh majority of the times I do not get the data.

Below is my setup for the following.

```
/* eslint-disable flowtype/no-types-missing-file-annotation */
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

import { split, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client'
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context'
import { WebSocketLink } from '@apollo/client/link/ws'
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities'
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
const domain = env === 'development' ? 'localhost' : '.xyz'
const url = env === 'development' ? 'https://staging-xxx.xxxx.xx' : process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
const wsURL = env === 'development' ? 'wss://staging-xxx.xxxxx.xx/subscriptions' : process.env.REACT_APP_WSS_URL;
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: url,
  credentials: 'include'
})

const authLink = setContext((_: any, { headers }: any) => {
  const app_token = Cookies.get('xxxxx', { domain: domain })
  let token = app_token || 'insta-checkout'
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      MUDEY_AUTH_TOKEN: token
    }
  }
})

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: wsURL,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: async () => {
      const app_token = await Cookies.get('xxxxx', { domain: domain })
      return {
        credentials: 'include',
        MUDEY_AUTH_TOKEN: app_token,
        Authorization: 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
    }
  }
})

const link = split(
  ({ query }: any) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query)
    return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && definition.operation === 'subscription'
  },
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink)
)
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([link])
})

export default client
```

Now when i go my component for the first time, i am calling the subscriptions api by

```
import React from "react";
import { useMutation, useSubscription } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

export const NewComponent = () => {
  const {
    loading: loadingPackages,
    data,
    error,
  } = useSubscription(SUBSCRIBE_CAR_PACKAGES, {
    onSubscriptionData: useCallback((res: any) => {
      const {
        subscribeCarJourneyPackages: { message: stopWS, data: packagesResult },
      } = res.subscriptionData.data;
      if (packagesResult !== null) {
        console.log("packarray", packagesResult);
        setIsSubsLoading(true);
      }

      if (stopWS === "SUBSCRIPTION_COMPLETE") {
        dispatch({ type: SET_ALL_PACKAGES, payload: packArray });
        setIsSubsLoading(false);
      } else {
        // setIsSubsLoading(true)
      }
    }, []),
    onError: useCallback((err: any) => {
      apiErrorHandler(err);
    }, []),
    variables: { id: journeyID },
  });
  return null;
};
```

So the response i see is [image: here]

But once i start refreshing the page , i only see [image: this]

So what the issue in my frontend, for not getting the response 100% of the time ? should we need to close the connection everytime we receive response ?

Also i see the subscription api hitting even when i am in my homepage, where ideally it should hit in the results page where i want it, do this happens the moment we define connection and is it normal?

Comment: I mean Is really hard to say just from your code samples and screenshots. But I would suggest you to investigate if auth is ready when you are connecting (if the proper auth data is send). Also if all the data is ready before using the  subscriptions api. It looks like something is not properly loaded (or is not ready to be loaded), but I can't say for sure what.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but it maybe help someone else !

try giving `fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'` as option below your variables field.

like this :

```
  variables: {... your variables },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
```